# Comparando values() do dicionário com valores da lista

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Tenho o seguinte dicionário e uma lista; do dicionário eu extraí os 10 maiores valores.
A minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Preciso comparar as chaves dos respectivos valores extraido do dictMaior com a lista. Por exemplo, a keys() do value() 72 é o 19, e o 19 está na lista?
Preciso de um código que me retorne uma lista contendo todos os valores do dictMaior que está presente na lista.
Tentei com items(), mais não deu certo
ex. dictMaior = heapq.nlargest(10, dicionario.items())

```py
import heapq

dicionario = {1: 68, 2: 53, 3: 57, 4: 56, 5: 60, 6: 58, 7: 62, 8: 53, 9: 57, 10: 64, 11: 53, 12: 54, 13: 64, 14: 58, 15: 63, 16: 61, 17: 56, 18: 64, 19: 72, 20: 65, 21: 63, 22: 55, 23: 57, 24: 62, 25: 65}

lista = [21, 20, 23, 8, 10, 18, 19, 2, 12, 14, 4, 9, 22, 16, 5]

# Extraindo os 10 maiores itens do dicionário através do values()
dictMaior = heapq.nlargest(10, dicionario.values())
# Saida do dictMaior:
# [72, 68, 65, 65, 64, 64, 64, 63, 63, 62]
```

Answer (score 1):

Grato a todos que colaboraram comigo, mas após comer muita documentação cheguei no seguinte código abaixo que satisfez minha necessidade. Achei por melhor usar "collections" e deu muito certo...
Obs.: A lista e o dicionário é apenas uma adaptação de um csv de 1831 linhas, apenas simplifiquei para poder postar aqui...
Grato pelo esforço de todos!

```py
from collections import Counter

lista = [21, 20, 23, 8, 10, 18, 19, 2, 12, 14, 4, 9, 22, 16, 5]
dicionario = {1: 68, 2: 53, 3: 57, 4: 56, 5: 60, 6: 58, 7: 62, 8: 53, 9: 57, 10: 64, 11: 53, 12: 54, 13: 64, 14: 58, 15: 63, 16: 61, 17: 56, 18: 64, 19: 72, 20: 65, 21: 63, 22: 55, 23: 57, 24: 62, 25: 65}
numeros_presentes = []

cnt = Counter(dicionario)
ordenado = cnt.most_common()
ordenado = ordenado[0:10]

for num in ordenado:
    if num[0] in lista:
        numeros_presentes.append(num[0])

print(numeros_presentes)

# Saída do código:
# [19, 20, 10, 18, 21]
```

Comment: +1, já agora: a função `most_common` pode levar o número de pares pretendidos`most_common(10)`

Answer (score 0):

Bom ficou um pouco confuso ainda mais por que o retorno que cheguei é uma lista vazia mas vamos lá:

Você tem uma lista chamada:
 `lista = [21, 20, 23, 8, 10, 18, 19, 2, 12, 14, 4, 9, 22, 16, 5]`

e uma outra lista chamada: `dictMaior = [72, 68, 65, 65, 64, 64, 64, 63, 63, 62]`

O que você precisa verificar é se algum número do dictMaior está na lista então: `numeros_presentes = [num for num in dictMaior if num in lista]`

Em outras palavras `num` vai ser o nome atribuído a cada valor no `dictMaior` então se `num` estiver presente na `lista` ele vai ser retornado dentro de `numeros_presentes`.

Comment: Filipe Gonçalves, grato irmão, valeu msm! Você quase chegou lá. Mas a grande sacada aqui era comparar as chaves do dicionario referente aos valores do dictMaior com a lista; por exemplo: a chave de 72 é o 19, a chave de 68 é o 1, e o "19 e o 1" estão na lista? Oque eu precisava era esse retorno, uma lista contendo os numeros que estão presentes em ambos os lugares.

Answer (score 0):

Só uma variante da versão do @Claudinei usando listas em compreensão

```
from collections import Counter
lista = [ 21 ......
dic = { 1:68 ......
print([k for k,c in Counter(dic).most_common(10) if k in lista])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dicionario = {1: 68, 2: 53, 3: 57, 4: 56, 5: 60, 6: 58, 7: 62, 8: 53, 9: 57, 10: 64, 11: 53, 12: 54, 13: 64, 14: 58, 15: 63, 16: 61, 17: 56, 18: 64, 19: 72, 20: 65, 21: 63, 22: 55, 23: 57, 24: 62, 25: 65}
lista = [21, 20, 23, 8, 10, 18, 19, 2, 12, 14, 4, 9, 22, 16, 5]
lista2 = []
a = 0
for x in lista:
   lista2.append(dicionario[x])
   a += 1
lista2.sort(reverse=True)
print(lista2)
```

Comment: Allan, você só colou um código (sem formatação).. O ideal seria você explicar o quê e como você fez para chegar no resultado que o AP precisa.